# How to have multiple data-bind attributes on one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I need to have multiple data bindings on one element. For example, I want a `href` as well as a `html` data-binding on *one* `a` tag. I have tried this,

```html
<a data-bind="html: name" 
   data-bind="attr: { href: url }" 
   data-bind="attr: { 'data-prop': xyz }">
</a>
```

But this doesn't work. It seems knockout only supports binding *one* `data-bind` property? How to bind both the `href`, the inner `html`, and a custom "`data-prop`" attribute on one element?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Like this:

```html
<a data-bind="html: name, attr: { href: url }">
```

You use comma-separated bindings - the attribute is the same as passing an object:

```html
{
    html: name, 
    attr: { href: url }
}
```

Or, if you're asking about multiple `attr` bindings at once:

```html
<a data-bind="html: name, attr: { href: url, 'data-prop': FullName }">
```

Comment: Can you also tell me that, if viewModel.tasks = ko.observableArray(tsks) then changing viewModel.tasks = [new Array], How to tell knock that array is changed

Comment: when setting a ko.observable value, try doing it like this: `viewModel.tasks([1,2,3]);`. I.e. you call it as a function, passing the new value as a parameter

Answer (score 3):

This is how I implemented the source attribute and click event using data-bind. You may find it useful.

```
<img data-bind="{click: function(data, event) {ESVendorWidget.loadFunction(data,event)},
                 attr: {src: $data.Photo.PhotoUrl }}"
     alt="package pic" class="big" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I simply use:

```
<input type="checkbox"
    data-bind="click: callFunction(), checkedValue: 0, checked: Card.Days">
```

for a checkbox element.

Answer (score 2):

**you can use multiple properties using `,`   like below**

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: url, id: id , class: classvalue}">
```

object like this

```
{ url: 'http://stackoverflow.com', id:'newid' , classvalue: 'classname' }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like below

> data-bind="text: method.method_title, attr: {'id': 'label_method_' +
> method.method_code}"

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Also, you should check how to format your posts properly here 
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code