# How to apply multiple template bindings on one element in angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-template

I'm using template like following:

```
<ul [ngClass]="{dispN: !shwFilter,'list-group':true,'autoS':true,'dispB':shwFilter,'myshddw':true}" style=";display: none">
  <li *ngIf="itsNotF && itsNotF.length" [ngClass]="{bgDFF: !colps[j],'list-group-item':true}" *ngFor="let valm1 of itsNotF;let j=index;" (click)="togFltr(j)" style="padding: 0;background: #fff">
    <div *ngIf="valm1 && valm1.type=='1'">
      <h5 style="padding:8px;margin: 0;">{{valm1['header']}}</h5>
      <p style="margin: 8px;">{{valm1['body']}}</p>
      <h6 style="padding:8px;margin: 0;">{{valm1['note']}}</h6>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="valm1 && valm1.type=='2'" (click)="modlTxt=valm1;notREadVu(j)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      <h5 style="padding:8px;margin: 0;">{{valm1['header']}}</h5>
      <h6 style="padding:8px;margin: 0;">{{valm1['note']}}</h6>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="valm1 && valm1.type=='3'">
      <h5 style="padding:8px;margin: 0;">{{valm1['header']}}</h5>
      <p style="margin: 8px;">{{valm1['body']}}</p>
      <h6 style="padding:8px;margin: 0;">{{valm1['note']}}</h6>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li [ngClass]="{bgDFF: !colps[j],'list-group-item':true,'lgOt':true}" (click)="logout()">
    <span class="title">Log Out <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So it gives following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with * ("one">
  <li *ngIf="itsNotF && itsNotF.length" [ngClass]="{bgDFF: !colps[j],'list-group-item':true}" [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let valm1 of itsNotF;let j=index;" (click)="togFltr(j)" style="padding: 0;background: #fff">
"): App@78:94
```

> Previously it was not giving error I faced this issue after upgrading to RC4.
>
> So what's workaround, so I can apply multiple template binding on single element without altering Template structure.

Comment: `ngIf` & `ngFor` both are structural directives, they can't be there on same element.. For workaroud you could check this [github issue coment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7315#issuecomment-232083676)

Comment: But previously(RC1) it was working.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Can't use two template binding on one element in Angular 2 (like *ngIf and *ngFor). But you can achieve the same by wrapping the element with a span or any other element. It is good to append with an `<ng-container>` as it is a logical container and it will not get append to the DOM. For example,

```
<ng-container *ngIf="condition">
    <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{item}}
    </li>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: this solution doesn't work always. for instance two ng-containers

Comment: I just changed as adding div with *ngIf="condition" instead of this ng-container. Meanwhile, I use angular 6. This change works for me.

Comment: I tried with wrapping with div. It didn't work. ng-container is most appropriate element, because it is logical wrapper. Thanks Man

Answer (score 15):

You can use the following (expanded version) to preserve the document structure (e.g. for your css selectors):

```
<template [ngIf]="itsNotF && itsNotF.length">
    <div [ngClass]="{bgDFF: !colps[j],'list-group-item':true}" *ngFor="let valm1 of itsNotF;let j=index;" (click)="togFltr(j)" style="padding: 0;background: #fff">
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4):

Put your *ngIf in a parent div, and the *ngFor can stay where it is.

For example:

```
<div *ngIf="itsNotF && itsNotF.length">
    <div [ngClass]="{bgDFF: !colps[j],'list-group-item':true}" *ngFor="let valm1 of itsNotF;let j=index;" (click)="togFltr(j)" style="padding: 0;background: #fff">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But for this I have to alter the template structure and CSS (Corresponding selector). Isn't there any Other workaround without altering Template structure.

Comment: Isn't there any solution similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700020/how-to-have-multiple-data-bind-attributes-on-one-element

Comment: That is true. You could define the parent as a span if it helps your CSS.  Or even make a custom element:  `<test *ngIf="1==1"><div></div></test>` for example

Comment: Although it's a bit rubbish, one option would be to make the div element invisible using `display:none` and then use `*ngFor`.  However, that wouldn't remove the element from the DOM like `*ngIf` does, so it's not very nice

Comment: Now I updated My scenario Now you can understand why I cant use your solution Because line logout will always be visible and altering ul>li selector is not possible(Lots of changes requires in css).

Comment: So only solution I'm getting is I have to replicate ul with *ngIf condition

Comment: Nah... But thx anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using *ngFor and want to add *ngIf to check some field, if conditional is not too complicated, I use filter for that, where I run my conditional and return only items that enter in my condition inside that loop.. Hope it helps

something like that where I want to show only items with description:

```
<div class="delivery-disclaimer" *ngFor="let payment of cart.restaurant.payment_method | filter:[{short_name: cart.payment_method}] | onlyDescription" text-wrap>
        <ion-icon item-left name="information-circle"></ion-icon> {{payment.pivot.description}}
    </div>
```

davor

Comment: Angular 2 does not has a filter method. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#no-filter-pipe.