# ngIf on BSDropdown

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I have below angular snippet. It uses BSDropdownModule from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown'. Now I want to add condition based on which the dropdown should be visible. in below code I want to add it at 'ul' level. But *ngIf in 'ul' gives error. I tried search and finding document for this but didn't found any. Your help or reference to documents is highly appreciated.

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Can you specify the error your getting

Comment: Can you please share console errors ?

Comment: Thanks guys. for such quick respose. here is the error from console.
Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with * ("pdown <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="false">
<li *ngIf="false" role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-dropdown?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: FOUND SOLUTION : so this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846773/5024215