# ng if with ngfor in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to display data in `cdkDroplist` for drag drop purposes

```
<div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="lists[0].answers" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of lists[0].answers"  *ngIf="item" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
```

i want to hide this div when `item` contains blank on `null` values

```
 <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of lists[0].answers"  *ngIf="item" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div></div>
```

for that i used `*ngIf="item"` but this is showing this error :

> Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one
> attribute prefixed with *

Comment: see if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/43846773/2460773

Comment: @NitsanBaleli Thanks but `item` variable  is accessible only inside for loop then how will i create outer div and get `item` variable access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do is wrap the for in a `ng-container` its a elemant that will not be shown in the dom

```
<div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="lists[0].answers" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
   <ng-container *ngFor="let item of lists[0].answers" >
       <div class="example-box"  *ngIf="item" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```